# how can i refresh Particular UITabeviewCell through NSTimer?

Tags: iphone

how can i refresh Particular UITabeviewCell through NSTimer? is it possible?
any help pls?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could just call the `reloadData` method of your UITableView. It will only refresh visible cells. There's also `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation` in OS 3.0+

The easiest approach if you don't have special needs would be: (assuming `myTableView` has a pointer to your `UITableView`)

```
NSTimeInterval someDelay = 5; // seconds
[myTableView performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil
    afterDelay:someDelay];
```

If your ViewController could disappear before the performSelector fires, be safe and call:

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:myTableView
    selector:@selector(reloadData) object:nil];
```